# How can i increase the maximum url length limit in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server

I am using SharePoint 2013 on premises. Please let me know, is it possible to upload a file exceeds more than 260 characters url length.

"The specified file or folder name is too long. The URL path for all files and folders must be 260 characters or less (and no more than 260 characters for any single file or folder name in the URL). Please type a shorter file or folder name."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. This value is hard coded into SharePoint's own code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have limit in the complete url length (default 256), i’ts possible increase the max url length via web.config

I’ve this problem on SharePoint 2013 on premises workflow task “copy to”

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8346a849-2e0c-4300-b68d-d7ab850d854c/the-length-of-the-url-for-this-request-exceeds-the-configured-maxurllength-value?forum=appsforsharepoint